# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' after decoding json in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-test, provider

I'm new in Flutter ,  I managed to find how to access specific parts of the values in the json tree and print those values of specific keys in a map. But now I'm getting the error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

This is my provider where im getting the json and decoding the data i've gotten

```
Future<String> getOrders(
    String token,
    String status,
  ) async {
    try {
      print(token);
      var url = Uri.parse("${Urls.flipteriaUrl}/Order?ProductStatus=$status");
      http.Response response = await http.get(
        url,
        headers: {
          "accept": "text/plain",
          "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json",
          "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
        },
      );
      var data = response.body;
      var decodedData = json.decode(data);
      if (status == "1") {
        _pendinOrders = decodedData;
      } else if (status == "2") {
        _readyToShipOrders = decodedData;
      } else if (status == "3") {
        _shippedOrders = decodedData;
      } else if (status == "4") {
        _deliveredOrders = decodedData;
      } else if (status == "5") {
        _cancelledOrders = decodedData;
      } else if (status == "6") {
        _returnedOrders = decodedData;
      } else if (status == "7") {
        _failedOrders = decodedData;
      }
      print(decodedData);
      notifyListeners();
      return "Successful";
    } catch (e) {
      print("Order error: $e");
      notifyListeners();
      return e.toString();
    }
  }
```

This is where i'm making use of it
It returns type "string" is not a subtype of type "int" of "index"

```
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  children: [
                    OrderTileIWidget(
                      id: _pendingOrders["data"]["orderNo"] ?? "",
                      time: _pendingOrders["data"]["createdOn"] ?? "",
                      grandTotal:
                          _pendingOrders["data"]["grandAmount"].toString(),
                      subTotal: _pendingOrders["data"]["subAmount"].toString(),
                      name: _pendingOrders["data"]["orderItems"]["itemName"] ??
                          "",
                      quantity: _pendingOrders["data"]["orderItems"]["quantity"]
                          .toString(),
                      imageUrl:
                          _pendingOrders["data"]["orderItems"]["image"] ?? "",
                    ),
                  ].toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
  }

  void init() async {
    setState(() {
      _isFetching = true;
    });
    final getToken = await UserSecureStorage.getToken() ?? "";

    if (mounted) {}
    final orderProvider = Provider.of<OrderProvider>(context, listen: false);

    final result = await orderProvider.getOrders(getToken, "1");

    _pendingOrders = orderProvider.pendingOrders;
    print(_pendingOrders);

    if (result == "Successful") {
      setState(() {
        _isFetching = false;
      });
    } else {
      if (mounted) {}
      setState(() {
        _isFetching = false;
      });
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          content: Text(
            "Failed to load pending order, please check internet connection and pull to refresh.",
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    setState(() {
      _isFetching = false;
    });
  }
}
```

The decoded json data, the value i want to access is the list data:

```
{
    "pageIndex": 1,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "count": 83,
    "data": [
        {
            "orderId": 904,
            "orderGuid": "f64ab54d-6b49-4d15-9c83-e25521d743f9",
            "customerId": 65,
            "orderedDate": "2022-11-21T15:23:33.8826189",
            "shippingAgentId": null,
            "itemCount": 1,
            "subAmount": 750.00,
            "grandAmount": 4292.50,
            "shippingAmount": 3500.00,
            "taxAmount": 0.00,
            "currency": "LKR",
            "recordStatus": "Active",
            "paymentType": "Cash On Delivery",
            "customerAddressId": null,
            "createdOn": "2022-11-21T15:23:33.8826125",
            "orderNo": "804621214690813",
            "itemTotalSum": 1.00,
            "grandTotalSum": 4250.0000,
            "shippingTotalSum": 3500.00,
            "subTotalSum": 800.0000,
            "discountTotalSum": 50.0000,
            "shippingAddress": {
                "customerAddressId": 150,
                "customerAddressGuid": "cdaca2fe-2ce6-4f86-8f84-ab5b5f292803",
                "customerId": 65,
                "name": "Test add UK",
                "address": "bHhabba",
                "cityId": 2151,
                "countryId": 3,
                "stateId": 17,
                "regionId": 51,
                "contactNumber1": "484664",
                "contactNumber2": null,
                "contactNumber3": null,
                "isDefault": true,
                "addressType": 1,
                "isShippingAddress": false,
                "recordStatus": 1,
                "createdOn": "2022-08-31T18:24:10.4862169",
                "country": null,
                "state": null,
                "region": null,
                "city": null
            },
            "billingAddress": {
                "customerAddressId": 150,
                "customerAddressGuid": "cdaca2fe-2ce6-4f86-8f84-ab5b5f292803",
                "customerId": 65,
                "name": "Test add UK",
                "address": "bHhabba",
                "cityId": 2151,
                "countryId": 3,
                "stateId": 17,
                "regionId": 51,
                "contactNumber1": "484664",
                "contactNumber2": null,
                "contactNumber3": null,
                "isDefault": true,
                "addressType": 1,
                "isShippingAddress": false,
                "recordStatus": 1,
                "createdOn": "2022-08-31T18:24:10.4862169",
                "country": null,
                "state": null,
                "region": null,
                "city": null
            },
            "orderItems": [
                {
                    "orderItemId": 1014,
                    "orderItemGuid": "8498253d-a835-4c6c-bdf9-5ed3c3b45dd6",
                    "orderId": 904,
                    "qanatity": 1.00,
                    "price": 800.00,
                    "discountPrice": 750.00,
                    "totalPrice": 750.00,
                    "image": "d737-0ee3-4b61.jpg",
                    "createdOn": "2022-11-21T15:23:34.6913537",
                    "sellerName": "basith",
                    "estimatedDeliveryTo": "2022-12-01T15:23:34.6913527",
                    "estimatedDeliveryFrom": "2022-11-29T15:23:34.6913468",
                    "orderItemStatus": 1,
                    "orderItemStatusDesc": "Pending",
                    "orderStatusHistory": [],
                    "itemName": "Amazon Basics Gold Plated 6.35mm 1/4 Male to 3.5mm 1/8 Female Stereo Headphone Adapter - 2-Pack",
                    "itemId": "352",
                    "shippingFee": 3500.00,
                    "isPrinted": false,
                    "flipteriaSKU": "2mTzQuV4xa_LK",
                    "sellerSKU": "5",
                    "returnStatus": null,
                    "comments": null,
                    "invoiceNo": "INV1014489527",
                    "seller": null,
                    "weight": 0.0,
                    "currency": "LKR"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "orderId": 903,
            "orderGuid": "93fda83d-c238-4117-8223-79e15705f8bb",
            "customerId": 65,
            "orderedDate": "2022-11-21T15:12:36.6812068",
            "shippingAgentId": null,
            "itemCount": 1,
            "subAmount": 750.00,
            "grandAmount": 4292.50,
            "shippingAmount": 3500.00,
            "taxAmount": 0.00,
            "currency": "LKR",
            "recordStatus": "Active",
            "paymentType": "Cash On Delivery",
            "customerAddressId": null,
            "createdOn": "2022-11-21T15:12:36.6811497",
            "orderNo": "804620557761886",
            "itemTotalSum": 1.00,
            "grandTotalSum": 4250.0000,
            "shippingTotalSum": 3500.00,
            "subTotalSum": 800.0000,
            "discountTotalSum": 50.0000,
            "shippingAddress": {
                "customerAddressId": 150,
                "customerAddressGuid": "cdaca2fe-2ce6-4f86-8f84-ab5b5f292803",
                "customerId": 65,
                "name": "Test add UK",
                "address": "bHhabba",
                "cityId": 2151,
                "countryId": 3,
                "stateId": 17,
                "regionId": 51,
                "contactNumber1": "484664",
                "contactNumber2": null,
                "contactNumber3": null,
                "isDefault": true,
                "addressType": 1,
                "isShippingAddress": false,
                "recordStatus": 1,
                "createdOn": "2022-08-31T18:24:10.4862169",
                "country": null,
                "state": null,
                "region": null,
                "city": null
            },
            "billingAddress": {
                "customerAddressId": 150,
                "customerAddressGuid": "cdaca2fe-2ce6-4f86-8f84-ab5b5f292803",
                "customerId": 65,
                "name": "Test add UK",
                "address": "bHhabba",
                "cityId": 2151,
                "countryId": 3,
                "stateId": 17,
                "regionId": 51,
                "contactNumber1": "484664",
                "contactNumber2": null,
                "contactNumber3": null,
                "isDefault": true,
                "addressType": 1,
                "isShippingAddress": false,
                "recordStatus": 1,
                "createdOn": "2022-08-31T18:24:10.4862169",
                "country": null,
                "state": null,
                "region": null,
                "city": null
            },
            "orderItems": [
                {
                    "orderItemId": 1013,
                    "orderItemGuid": "526e46ca-230f-4563-b0d3-6759ff8b3d37",
                    "orderId": 903,
                    "qanatity": 1.00,
                    "price": 800.00,
                    "discountPrice": 750.00,
                    "totalPrice": 750.00,
                    "image": "d737-0ee3-4b61.jpg",
                    "createdOn": "2022-11-21T15:12:37.9653245",
                    "sellerName": "basith",
                    "estimatedDeliveryTo": "2022-12-01T15:12:37.965323",
                    "estimatedDeliveryFrom": "2022-11-29T15:12:37.9653164",
                    "orderItemStatus": 1,
                    "orderItemStatusDesc": "Pending",
                    "orderStatusHistory": [],
                    "itemName": "Amazon Basics Gold Plated 6.35mm 1/4 Male to 3.5mm 1/8 Female Stereo Headphone Adapter - 2-Pack",
                    "itemId": "352",
                    "shippingFee": 3500.00,
                    "isPrinted": false,
                    "flipteriaSKU": "2mTzQuV4xa_LK",
                    "sellerSKU": "5",
                    "returnStatus": null,
                    "comments": null,
                    "invoiceNo": "INV0357385388",
                    "seller": null,
                    "weight": 0.0,
                    "currency": "LKR"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "orderId": 892,
            "orderGuid": "ab6849a0-9e53-4a16-9c89-510ccbf93ba1",
            "customerId": 1,
            "orderedDate": "2022-10-21T21:15:35.6518571",
            "shippingAgentId": null,
            "itemCount": 1,
            "subAmount": 5100.00,
            "grandAmount": 5252.00,
            "shippingAmount": 100.00,
            "taxAmount": 0.00,
            "currency": "LKR",
            "recordStatus": "Active",
            "paymentType": "Cash On Delivery",
            "customerAddressId": null,
            "createdOn": "2022-10-21T21:15:35.6517697",
            "orderNo": "801983735997944",
            "itemTotalSum": 1.00,
            "grandTotalSum": 5200.0000,
            "shippingTotalSum": 100.00,
            "subTotalSum": 5500.0000,
            "discountTotalSum": 400.0000,
            "shippingAddress": {
                "customerAddressId": 131,
                "customerAddressGuid": "1db1ebca-beff-45a4-9512-34cb651080c6",
                "customerId": 1,
                "name": "Test 123",
                "address": "Test 123",
                "cityId": 1860,
                "countryId": 1,
                "stateId": 1,
                "regionId": 11,
                "contactNumber1": "8912387617286312",
                "contactNumber2": null,
                "contactNumber3": null,
                "isDefault": true,
                "addressType": 1,
                "isShippingAddress": false,
                "recordStatus": 1,
                "createdOn": "2022-06-17T20:31:16.5511411",
                "country": null,
                "state": null,
                "region": null,
                "city": null
            },
            "billingAddress": {
                "customerAddressId": 131,
                "customerAddressGuid": "1db1ebca-beff-45a4-9512-34cb651080c6",
                "customerId": 1,
                "name": "Test 123",
                "address": "Test 123",
                "cityId": 1860,
                "countryId": 1,
                "stateId": 1,
                "regionId": 11,
                "contactNumber1": "8912387617286312",
                "contactNumber2": null,
                "contactNumber3": null,
                "isDefault": true,
                "addressType": 1,
                "isShippingAddress": false,
                "recordStatus": 1,
                "createdOn": "2022-06-17T20:31:16.5511411",
                "country": null,
                "state": null,
                "region": null,
                "city": null
            },
            "orderItems": [
                {
                    "orderItemId": 1002,
                    "orderItemGuid": "f0843811-94f3-42e4-b490-6ee04723990c",
                    "orderId": 892,
                    "qanatity": 1.00,
                    "price": 5500.00,
                    "discountPrice": 5100.00,
                    "totalPrice": 5100.00,
                    "image": "36ac-d8ea-c52c.jpg",
                    "createdOn": "2022-10-21T21:15:36.032462",
                    "sellerName": "basith",
                    "estimatedDeliveryTo": "2022-10-27T21:15:36.0320501",
                    "estimatedDeliveryFrom": "2022-10-23T21:15:36.0319402",
                    "orderItemStatus": 1,
                    "orderItemStatusDesc": "Pending",
                    "orderStatusHistory": [],
                    "itemName": "Core 10 by Reebok Women's Oversized Color Block Crewneck Sweatshirt",
                    "itemId": "231",
                    "shippingFee": 100.00,
                    "isPrinted": false,
                    "flipteriaSKU": "e6XMUGmiT3_LK",
                    "sellerSKU": "4",
                    "returnStatus": null,
                    "comments": null,
                    "invoiceNo": "INV3735856871",
                    "seller": null,
                    "weight": 0.0,
                    "currency": "LKR"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "orderId": 891,
            "orderGuid": "c948d87f-a854-448b-be43-a46c9a055374",
            "customerId": 1,
            "orderedDate": "2022-10-21T21:01:07.2846167",
            "shippingAgentId": null,
            "itemCount": 1,
            "subAmount": 750.00,
            "grandAmount": 858.50,
            "shippingAmount": 100.00,
            "taxAmount": 0.00,
            "currency": "LKR",
            "recordStatus": "Active",
            "paymentType": "Cash On Delivery",
            "customerAddressId": null,
            "createdOn": "2022-10-21T21:01:07.2845218",
            "orderNo": "801982867662308",
            "itemTotalSum": 1.00,
            "grandTotalSum": 850.0000,
            "shippingTotalSum": 100.00,
            "subTotalSum": 800.0000,
            "discountTotalSum": 50.0000,
            "shippingAddress": {
                "customerAddressId": 131,
                "customerAddressGuid": "1db1ebca-beff-45a4-9512-34cb651080c6",
                "customerId": 1,
                "name": "Test 123",
                "address": "Test 123",
                "cityId": 1860,
                "countryId": 1,
                "stateId": 1,
                "regionId": 11,
                "contactNumber1": "8912387617286312",
                "contactNumber2": null,
                "contactNumber3": null,
                "isDefault": true,
                "addressType": 1,
                "isShippingAddress": false,
                "recordStatus": 1,
                "createdOn": "2022-06-17T20:31:16.5511411",
                "country": null,
                "state": null,
                "region": null,
                "city": null
            },
            "billingAddress": {
                "customerAddressId": 131,
                "customerAddressGuid": "1db1ebca-beff-45a4-9512-34cb651080c6",
                "customerId": 1,
                "name": "Test 123",
                "address": "Test 123",
                "cityId": 1860,
                "countryId": 1,
                "stateId": 1,
                "regionId": 11,
                "contactNumber1": "8912387617286312",
                "contactNumber2": null,
                "contactNumber3": null,
                "isDefault": true,
                "addressType": 1,
                "isShippingAddress": false,
                "recordStatus": 1,
                "createdOn": "2022-06-17T20:31:16.5511411",
                "country": null,
                "state": null,
                "region": null,
                "city": null
            },
            "orderItems": [
                {
                    "orderItemId": 1001,
                    "orderItemGuid": "d25f92b1-68ea-4737-9b07-7da6fd36bc7e",
                    "orderId": 891,
                    "qanatity": 1.00,
                    "price": 800.00,
                    "discountPrice": 750.00,
                    "totalPrice": 750.00,
                    "image": "d737-0ee3-4b61.jpg",
                    "createdOn": "2022-10-21T21:01:07.6894446",
                    "sellerName": "basith",
                    "estimatedDeliveryTo": "2022-10-27T21:01:07.6891643",
                    "estimatedDeliveryFrom": "2022-10-23T21:01:07.6891131",
                    "orderItemStatus": 1,
                    "orderItemStatusDesc": "Pending",
                    "orderStatusHistory": [],
                    "itemName": "Amazon Basics Gold Plated 6.35mm 1/4 Male to 3.5mm 1/8 Female Stereo Headphone Adapter - 2-Pack",
                    "itemId": "352",
                    "shippingFee": 100.00,
                    "isPrinted": false,
                    "flipteriaSKU": "2mTzQuV4xa_LK",
                    "sellerSKU": "5",
                    "returnStatus": null,
                    "comments": null,
                    "invoiceNo": "INV2867520928",
                    "seller": null,
                    "weight": 0.0,
                    "currency": "LKR"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "orderId": 865,
            "orderGuid": "c7dd33f0-d7af-4dc7-bdaf-0f775c07589b",
            "customerId": 50,
            "orderedDate": "2022-09-26T12:24:30.0865457",
            "shippingAgentId": null,
            "itemCount": 1,
            "subAmount": 750.00,
            "grandAmount": 850.00,
            "shippingAmount": 100.00,
            "taxAmount": 0.00,
            "currency": "LKR",
            "recordStatus": "Active",
            "paymentType": "Cash On Delivery",
            "customerAddressId": null,
            "createdOn": "2022-09-26T12:24:30.0865402",
            "orderNo": "799772070209080",
            "itemTotalSum": 1.00,
            "grandTotalSum": 850.0000,
            "shippingTotalSum": 100.00,
            "subTotalSum": 800.0000,
            "discountTotalSum": 50.0000,
            "shippingAddress": {
                "customerAddressId": 100,
                "customerAddressGuid": "d07509ed-8246-4de7-af88-cd808db6b2e8",
                "customerId": 50,
                "name": "HT    ",
                "address": "wasana mw",
                "cityId": 1912,
                "countryId": 1,
                "stateId": 1,
                "regionId": 11,
                "contactNumber1": "70077070",
                "contactNumber2": null,
                "contactNumber3": null,
                "isDefault": false,
                "addressType": 1,
                "isShippingAddress": false,
                "recordStatus": 2,
                "createdOn": "2022-02-21T17:09:38.1003773",
                "country": null,
                "state": null,
                "region": null,
                "city": null
            },
            "billingAddress": {
                "customerAddressId": 100,
                "customerAddressGuid": "d07509ed-8246-4de7-af88-cd808db6b2e8",
                "customerId": 50,
                "name": "HT    ",
                "address": "wasana mw",
                "cityId": 1912,
                "countryId": 1,
                "stateId": 1,
                "regionId": 11,
                "contactNumber1": "70077070",
                "contactNumber2": null,
                "contactNumber3": null,
                "isDefault": false,
                "addressType": 1,
                "isShippingAddress": false,
                "recordStatus": 2,
                "createdOn": "2022-02-21T17:09:38.1003773",
                "country": null,
                "state": null,
                "region": null,
                "city": null
            },
            "orderItems": [
                {
                    "orderItemId": 971,
                    "orderItemGuid": "d759ff75-d14a-4dae-a42b-85fe6555af2b",
                    "orderId": 865,
                    "qanatity": 1.00,
                    "price": 800.00,
                    "discountPrice": 750.00,
                    "totalPrice": 750.00,
                    "image": "d737-0ee3-4b61.jpg",
                    "createdOn": "2022-09-26T12:24:30.2094077",
                    "sellerName": "basith",
                    "estimatedDeliveryTo": "2022-10-02T12:24:30.2094067",
                    "estimatedDeliveryFrom": "2022-09-28T12:24:30.2094021",
                    "orderItemStatus": 1,
                    "orderItemStatusDesc": "Pending",
                    "orderStatusHistory": [],
                    "itemName": "Amazon Basics Gold Plated 6.35mm 1/4 Male to 3.5mm 1/8 Female Stereo Headphone Adapter - 2-Pack",
                    "itemId": "352",
                    "shippingFee": 100.00,
                    "isPrinted": false,
                    "flipteriaSKU": "2mTzQuV4xa_LK",
                    "sellerSKU": "5",
                    "returnStatus": null,
                    "comments": null,
                    "invoiceNo": "INV1870178425",
                    "seller": null,
                    "weight": 0.0,
                    "currency": "LKR"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "orderId": 862,
            "orderGuid": "dc673afb-1734-4099-8096-50631e2553b3",
            "customerId": 1,
            "orderedDate": "2022-09-22T14:34:53.711407",
            "shippingAgentId": null,
            "itemCount": 1,
            "subAmount": 170000.00,
            "grandAmount": 170100.00,
            "shippingAmount": 100.00,
            "taxAmount": 0.00,
            "currency": "GBP",
            "recordStatus": "Active",
            "paymentType": "Cash On Delivery",
            "customerAddressId": null,
            "createdOn": "2022-09-22T14:34:53.7113942",
            "orderNo": "799434293839802",
            "itemTotalSum": 1.00,
            "grandTotalSum": 170100.0000,
            "shippingTotalSum": 100.00,
            "subTotalSum": 175000.0000,
            "discountTotalSum": 5000.0000,
            "shippingAddress": {
                "customerAddressId": 131,
                "customerAddressGuid": "1db1ebca-beff-45a4-9512-34cb651080c6",
                "customerId": 1,
                "name": "Test 123",
                "address": "Test 123",
                "cityId": 1860,
                "countryId": 1,
                "stateId": 1,
                "regionId": 11,
                "contactNumber1": "8912387617286312",
                "contactNumber2": null,
                "contactNumber3": null,
                "isDefault": true,
                "addressType": 1,
                "isShippingAddress": false,
                "recordStatus": 1,
                "createdOn": "2022-06-17T20:31:16.5511411",
                "country": null,
                "state": null,
                "region": null,
                "city": null
            },
```

Comment: could you print("decodedData = $decodedData");? and show us the result?

Comment: ive added the json data

Comment: there is no quantity key in the JSON data

Comment: that should be the count at the beginning if the json

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue because of the way you are using the `ListView`, `_pendingOrders["data"]` is a list, in order to get its item you need pass the index, change it to this:

```
ListView(
          children: (_pendingOrders["data"] as List)
              .map((value) => OrderTileIWidget(
                    id: value["orderNo"] ?? "",
                    time: value["createdOn"] ?? "",
                    grandTotal: value["grandAmount"].toString(),
                    subTotal: value["subAmount"].toString(),
                    name: value["orderItems"]["itemName"] ?? "",
                    quantity: (value["orderItems"] as List)
                        .map((e) => e["quantity"].toString())
                        .toList(),
                    imageUrl: (value["orderItems"] as List)
                        .map((e) => e["image"] ?? '')
                        .toList(),
                  ))
              .toList(),
        )
```

also you need change your `OrderTileIWidget` to this:

```
class OrderTileIWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const OrderTileIWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.id,
    required this.time,
    required this.grandTotal,
    required this.subTotal,
    required this.name,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.imageUrl,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String id;
  final String time;
  final String grandTotal;
  final String subTotal;
  final String name;
  final List<String> quantity; //<---- change this
  final List<String> imageUrl; //<---- change this

  ...
}
```

Comment: @Ariyo I updated my answer again, check it out.

Comment: @Ariyo was it what you want?

Comment: what should be added in the square brackets

Comment: In which square brackets? you don't need [] if you pass the children like this.  just replace my answer with your listview. @Ariyo

Comment: _pending["data"] doesn't return .map function

Comment: try this: `(_pendingOrders["data"] as List).map...`

Comment: I'm still getting the exact same error

Comment: could you show me the data inside it? print("data = ${_pendingOrders["data"]}") @Ariyo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249871/discussion-between-ariyo-and-eamirho3ein).